# Error "Reflect.defineMetadata" while trying to load a transient web worker

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to load the aurelia framework from inside a web worker in order to decorate the worker as transient. Here is the worker loader:

```js
importScripts('/jspm_packages/system.js');
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: 'none',
  paths: {
    'npm:*': '/jspm_packages/npm/*'
  },
  map: {
    'aurelia-framework': 'npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1',
    'aurelia-dependency-injection': 'npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-binding': 'npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-rc.1.0.2',
    'aurelia-metadata': 'npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-templating': 'npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-loader': 'npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-task-queue': 'npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-pal': 'npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-path': 'npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-logging': 'npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-polyfills': 'npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0',
    'aurelia-fetch-client': 'npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0/aurelia-fetch-client'
  }
});
System.import('files-service')
  .then(module => {
    let fs = new module.FilesService();
  });
```

Here is how I declare the worker class:

```js
@transient()
export class FilesService {
  constructor() {
    httpClient = new HttpClient();
    // rest of stuff
  }
}
```

I get back this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Reflect.defineMetadata is not a function
    at Object.define (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0/aurelia-metadata.js:49:15)
    at eval (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:245:33)
    at execute (http://localhost:9000/dist/files-service.js:93:67)
    at u (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:5:97)
    at Object.execute (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:5:3188)
    at y (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:9948)
    at w (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:10327)
    at p (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:8205)
    at h (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:8590)
    at http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:6896
    Error loading http://localhost:9000/dist/files-service.js
```

Any idea what might be wrong? BTW, if the worker is not declared as transient, there is no problem (in that case all these mappings are not required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `aurelia-pal-browser` package to your SystemJS map, then update your code to something like this:

```js
// Import Aurelia's [p]latform [a]bstraction [l]ibrary for the browser.
// The PAL does some basic feature detection and serves as an abstraction for
// browser globals.
System.import('aurelia-pal-browser')
  .then(pal => pal.initialize())
  // now import a small set of polyfills for things like Reflect.defineMetadata
  .then(() => System.import('aurelia-polyfills'))
  // now you should be all set...
  .then(() => System.import('files-service')
  .then(({ FilesService }) => {  // <-- look how fancy I am! ES6 destructuring FTW - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
    let fs = new FilesService();
  });
```

It looks like you want to use the container in your worker though- here's an example:

```js
let container = null;

System.import('aurelia-pal-browser')
  .then(({ initialize }) => initialize())
  .then(() => System.import('aurelia-polyfills'))
  // import DI and instantiate a container for the worker to use.
  .then(() => System.import('aurelia-dependency-injection'))
  .then(({ Container }) => container = new Container())
  // use the container...
  .then(() => System.import('files-service')
  .then(({ FilesService }) => {
    let fs = container.get(FilesService);
  });
```

Comment: Wow! That was really enlightening!

Comment: Unfortunately, aurelia-pal-browser gets stuck here: "return !!HTMLElement.prototype.attachShadow". Maybe because its being run from inside a web worker? I tried using aurelia-pal-nodejs instead, but didn't have much luck either. Any way to overcome this?

Comment: darn it. I hadn't thought of that.... I just discussed this with the team, including @EisenbergEffect. To make this work we need an implementation of the PAL for web/service workers. Would you be interested in working on that (aurelia-pal-worker)? It would essentially be a stripped down copy of [`aurelia-pal-browser`](https://github.com/aurelia/pal-browser/).

Comment: This is way over my head, I'm afraid, still I'll have a look. Do you need me to open an issue? If so, at which repo? Currently, neither aurelia-pal nor aurelia-pal-browser have any issues

Comment: Had a more careful look at the pal-nodejs work, as I assume that something similar is required. Again, this is way over my head. Until somebody else steps in, is there any other way to have a transient class inside a web worker?

Comment: No worries- we may have another community member take a look at it. Please open an issue in aurelia-pal

Comment: Further tests seem to indicate that importing aurelia-pal-browser may not actually be required. Importing the polyfills and then the worker class seems to be enough.