# Proper implementation of web workers in Aurelia and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, browserify, aurelia, web-worker

Sadly, I couldn't find a single answer to this on the whole web.

I have an Aurelia app based on `TypeScript` / `Aurelia CLI` / `RequireJS`.
With a structure like this:

```
|data
   |-MyService.ts
|workers
   |-SomeWorker.ts/js
```

There exists a package called [`aurelia-pal-worker`](https://github.com/aurelia/pal-worker), but without documentation or complex examples.

---

**What I've tried so far**

- [`Typed-Web-Workers`](https://github.com/anderscan/typed-web-workers) which is nice but too limiting
- Having a `SomeWorker`**.js** and used [Browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify-handbook#gulp) as an additional buildstep in *aurelia_project*.

The Browserify approach works, as long as I require external libs like `RxJs`.
Of course this breaks when I try to `require("../data/MyService.ts")`. For this to work, I would need to replace the whole build pipeline with another, that runs the entire aurelia project through Browserify with the tsify plugin.

It seems to my I've got 3 choices:

- Find a working example to compile a TypeScript file down to a web worker and use `aurelia-pal-worker` to import dependencies.
- Use `TypedWorker` and just throw expensive functions into a thread like:
  `new TypedWoker(expensiveFuncFromService, handleOutput)`
- Compile `MyService.ts` to separate JS-Files (instead of bundling it) and require it like this:
  `require("/scripts/MyService.js")`

The last two don't seem very appealing to me, but should be straightforward to do. Any hints or examples are highly appreciated!

PS: For anyone not familiar with Aurelia: It uses a gulp pipeline under the hood.

Comment: I don't believe the aurelia-pal-worker is quite what you're looking for, as it is simply an implementation of the Aurelia Platform Abstraction Layer for Web Workers. I believe it is part of work that might allow Aurelia to offload some framework tasks to Web Workers in the future.

Comment: @AshleyGrant thx for the quick reply! I was under the assumption that the `pal` provides a module loader abstraction that i could put to use here.

Comment: And regarding Web Workers + TypeScript and Aurelia, the answer to how to do this is likely going to be the same as the answer to how to do this in a non-Aurelia project. So if you can figure out how to do this in a TypeScript + RequireJS project, that should probably work in an Aurelia CLI project.

Comment: Makes sense; then I'll keep hacking the build pipeline and post an update later. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some fiddling around I switched to a [webpack based solution](https://github.com/Xceno/aurelia-skeleton-typescript-react-webpack), which allows me to use the amazing [webpack-worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader).

This was the best tradeoff between modifying my existing project and having it up and running again quickly.

This is how it looks like in the end:

**`custom_typings/worker-loader.d.ts`**

```ts
declare module "worker-loader!*" {
  const content: new () => any;
  export = content;
}
```

**`worker/some-service.ts`**

```ts
export class SomeService {
  public doStuff() {
    console.log("[SomeService] Stuff was done");
  }
}
```

**`worker/my-worker.ts`**

```ts
import "rxjs/add/observable/interval";

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { SomeService } from "./some-service";

const svc = new SomeService();
svc.doStuff();

console.log("[Worker] Did stuff");
onmessage = event => {
    console.log(event);
};

Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => postMessage(x));
```

After the worker is loaded like this:

```
import * as MyWorker from "worker-loader!./worker/my-worker";
const worker = new MyWorker();
worker.onmessage = msg => console.log("[MyClass] got msg from worker", msg);
```

It will generate the following console output:

```
1: "[SomeService] Stuff was done"
2: "[Worker] Did stuff"
3: "[MyClass] got msg from worker", 1
4: "[MyClass] got msg from worker", 2
...
```

**You need full blown DI in a worker?**

Fear not, with a little help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38294082/932315) I figured out how rewrite this with our webpack based solution:

```ts
let container: Container = null;
let myService: SuperComplexService = null;

// Import the loader abstraction, so the DI container knows how to resolve our modules.
import("aurelia-pal-worker")
  .then(pal => pal.initialize())
  // We need some polyfills (like "Reflect.defineMetadata")
  .then(() => import("aurelia-polyfills"))
  // Then we get the DI service and create a container
  .then(() => import("aurelia-dependency-injection"))
  .then(({ Container }) => (container = new Container()))
  .then(() => import("../services/my-super-complex-service")) // Here we go!
  .then(({ SuperComplexService }) => (myService = container.get(SuperComplexService) as SuperComplexService))
  .then(() => startWorker());

const startWorker = async() => {
  // Let's get going!
}
```

All credits for this loader-chain go to @jeremy-danyow.